# Error importing shapefile to PostGIS

Tags: postgis, shapefile, import

I'm trying to import a shapefile into a PostGIS database using the graphical importer. I just installed PostgreSQL, and PostGIS.

The error:

*Shapefile type: Polygon*

*PostGIS type: POLYGON[2]*

*We have a Multipolygon with 2 parts, can't use -S switch!*

*Shapefile import failed*

After testing that my database worked, I chose the shapefile that I wanted to upload, and then received a message that it had failed to import.

Are there any good tutorials or instructions about how to do this?

[image: PostGIS Shapefile Import Manager]

Comment: Where does QGIS come into play here?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Please remember to always include the full error message as text within the body of the Question; this makes it legible on all devices and searchable as well. Please [Edit] the question.

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to force a multipart polygon into a single part with the -S switch. Try without the -S

Comment: I agree with @BERA , it seems like you try to split the multipolygon. look in options and the checkbox : "generate simple geometries instead of MULTI", uncheck it if checked

Comment: you could try the QGIS DB Manager importer instead

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you to read this [shp2pgsql_usage](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.3/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html#shp2pgsql_usage) and [this tutorial](https://postgis.net/workshops/postgis-intro/loading_data.html) about loading spatial data.

As you see, -S key would try to generate simple geometries instead of MULTI geometries. BUT Will only succeed if all the geometries are actually single.
Your case is multipolygon with 2 parts, so do not use -S.

When trying to import Multigeometries, I usually check **Generate simple geometries instead of MULTI geometries** in the Options (subsection 6 in the tutorial) so import is successful.